# G script Performance/Overload on certain devices

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have with much ado created a gsheet based planning application for our team, where each player must record which practices he

1. will attend
2. might attend
3. cant attend

I have done this by creating a big 12 month schedule in a gsheet with all the various practice slots (field, gym, theory etc.) shown. Each player gets his own sheet in which to enter his planned attendance as described above.

In order to make sure that entries are not done outside of the valid slots I have through a script protected the sheet with many ranges (=practice slots) exempted (i.e. they are editable). In total the script creates about 1600 exampted ranges for one full year.

Note: the script is executed once by the owner of the sheet (=me) and no script is run by the players when maintaining the sheet with their availability.

It all works beautifully on the PC/laptop with which I have done the development and the testing, but stuuuuupid as I am it never occured to me that all devices are not created equal.

Hence, when I try to maintain the sheet from my own Android smartphone (8GB RAM, HUAWEI Kirin 980) the application freezes and it is impossible to maintain the sheet on that device.

Only when I reduce the number of exempted ranges to about 400 the sheet becomes editable on the phone.

Now my question: what can I do - if anything - in order to improve/fix the situation?

Hint: having all the players buy more powerful phones is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Your question is already answered by itself ... reduce the excepted ranges!

Comment: Hmm I hoping there might be some other less obvious options out there.

Comment: Have considered to split your spreadsheet in one spreadsheet for each month / each week?